# xmllint canonicalization is not sorting for elements and all child elements

Tags: xml, xmllint, c14n

how can We sort the below output using xmllint c14n option.

I have tried below options but i don't see any sorting happening here.
I'm expecting all elements and child elements to be sorted.

xmllint c14n

xmllint --exc-c14n

```
    <class-of-service>
            <rewrite-rules>
                <exp>
                    <name>BEST-EFFORT</name>
                    <forwarding-class>
                        <name>DATA</name>
                        <loss-priority>
                            <name>low</name>
                            <code-point>BEST-EFFORT</code-point>
                        </loss-priority>
                        <loss-priority>
                            <name>high</name>
                            <code-point>BEST-EFFORT</code-point>
                        </loss-priority>
                    </forwarding-class>
                </exp>
            </rewrite-rules>
            <code-point-aliases>
                <exp>
                    <name>BEST-EFFORT</name>
                    <bits>000</bits>
                </exp>
                <exp>
                    <name>EXP1</name>
                    <bits>001</bits>
                </exp>
            </code-point-aliases>
            <forwarding-classes>
                <class>
                    <name>DATA</name>
                    <queue-num>0</queue-num>
                </class>
                <class>
                    <name>REAL-TIME</name>
                    <queue-num>1</queue-num>
                </class>
            </forwarding-classes>
        </class-of-service>
```

Comment: Order of elements can be significant. Only attributes can be sorted without changing the semantics of the document.

Comment: Is that we can't sort the xml unless we have attributes ?

Comment: @choroba         I want to compare similar output which in different order and make sure both  .   Is that we can't sort the xml tree unless we have attributes ?

Comment: You can do whatever you like, but you'll need more than just an option to xmllint.

Comment: I'm giving like   xmllint c14n  data.xml  >  data_can.xml. Similarly I have one more file with same output but elements in different oder. I dont see any sorting with files.  Data in "data.xml"  is same as "data_can.xml"

Comment: Yes, you need to write a program to sort the elements.